# List of secret hats during Winter Bash 2021

Tags: discussion, support, winter-bash

Apparently a buried penny is a secret hat. I'm not sure what its criteria is. Also, is there a list of secret hats for this year's winter bash? Do the hats change every year?

2014 list:
[Winter Bash 2014 Secret Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245170/winter-bash-2014-secret-hats)

Comment: Truly? I think someone just had a lot of free time on their hands.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Winter Bash is network-wide, it is not surprising that such a list is on Meta Stack Exchange rather than here. (Also the [post which you linked in the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245170/winter-bash-2014-secret-hats) is on Meta Stack Exchange.)

You can find this question there: [Winter Bash 2021 Hat List](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372999)  . It has two answers - one for [secret hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372999/winter-bash-2021-hat-list/373001#373001) and one for [regular hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372999/winter-bash-2021-hat-list/373000#373000).

I will also add a link to the [Winter Bash 2021 chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/132350/winter-bash-2021) - which is also mentioned in that question.